# Symfony Request Object not being Injected in FosRest nested controller

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm having an issue with Symphony not injecting the Request object when specified in my controller, my code is as follows:

Routing.yml:

```
user:
  type: rest
  resource: AppBundle\Controller\UserController

user_comments:
  type: rest
  parent: user
  resource: AppBundle\Controller\UserCommentsController
```

And FosRest Controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserCommentsController extends BaseRestController
{

    public function postCommentAction(Request $request, $userId)
    {
        var_dump($request);

        return $this->view($userId, 201);
    }
```

My App doesn't respond at all to the route, however when I remove Request $request from postCommentAction it works as expected (but obviously I don't have access to the Request object).

dev.log:

```
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] request.INFO: Matched route "post_user_comment" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\UserCommentController::postCommentAction", "_format": "null", "userId": "a2fecac6-b7f6-4e00-8d03-989a9ee0973a", "_route": "post_user_comment") [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] security.INFO: Attempting simple pre-authorization secured_area [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\MimeTypeListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\FormatListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-05-29 10:32:21] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in your `app/logs/dev.log`?

Comment: Nothing other than some event.debugs really - I've updated question with the log can't see anything out of the ordinary and theres no visible error.

Comment: Do you get anything in your regular PHP or virtual host logs?

Comment: Can you please post the yaml/xml definition for the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone - issue was being caused by the var_dump($request) - a basic memory issue hidden in the VM, impressive considering PHP had access to ~512mb ram.